# Why is the inner div comming out of the parent div in this CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: "#00b7ff"
}

#content {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid blueviolet;
}

#room {
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#messages {
  width: 690px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <div id='room'></div>
  <div id='room-list'></div>
  <div id='messages'></div>

  <form id='send-form'>
    <input id='send-messsage' />
    <input type=s ubmit id='send-button' value='Send' />

    <div id='help'>
      Chat commands:
      <ul>
        <li>Change nickname: <code>/nick [username]</code> </li>
        <li>Join/create room: <code>/join [room name]</code> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Results in:

[image]

Please explain why is the inner rectangle coming out and what can be done to prevent it?

Comment: Where is content and messages id in your code?

Comment: @techie_questie the code was not being displayed properly. Please see it again now.

Comment: 300px + something inside 300px will for sure create an overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might help:

If we reduce the height of #message to 282px it will align properly.
Because the above div which is #room is taking 1em = 16px and the #content is taking 2px border. so total 18px it is coming out of the parent div.

I have tried the changes it is working fine.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: "#00b7ff"
}

#content {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid blueviolet;
}

#room {
  background-color: blurrywood;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#messages {
  width: 690px;
  height: 282px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <div id='room'></div>
  <div id='room-list'></div>
  <div id='messages'></div>

  <form id='send-form'>
    <input id='send-messsage' />
    <input type=s ubmit id='send-button' value='Send' />

    <div id='help'>
      Chat commands:
      <ul>
        <li>Change nickname: <code>/nick [username]</code> </li>
        <li>Join/create room: <code>/join [room name]</code> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  #content{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#messages{
line-height:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `#message` div is too big.
2. The default `overflow` property of the parent div is evidently set to `visible`.

Now, as for how to fix it, it depends on what you are trying to do.  But those are the two contributing factors.

Comment: I want to fit the inner div inside the boundaries of the parent div.